# .NET Core 1.1, Docker Build encounters Couldn't find 'project.json' with csproj

Tags: docker, dockerfile, .net-core, csproj

I upgraded an app from .NET Core 1.0 to 1.1. In the process, the dotnet build command started using a .csproj project file, so I got rid of the old project.json file. Everything works great until I try to run the docker build command:

docker build -t sample .

When it hits the RUN ["dotnet", "build"] command in Dockerfile, I get an error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.418 MB
Step 1 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
 ---> 3693707d4f7f
Step 2 : COPY . /app
 ---> 771e2b035ea1
Removing intermediate container c271f962518e
Step 3 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 6a07c60bab1d
 ---> e819bc2a9e25
Removing intermediate container 6a07c60bab1d
Step 4 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 99d1cf514fa3
warn : The folder '/app' does not contain a project to restore.
 ---> cf063f4db808
Removing intermediate container 99d1cf514fa3
Step 5 : RUN dotnet build
 ---> Running in c2ed65925939
Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directory
The command 'dotnet build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

But there is no 'project.json' file anymore. Why do I get this when I run docker build, but not when I run dotnet build?

Here is the full Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
CMD ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://*:5000"]
```

Comment: Are you sure project.json file is no longer necessary? Reading the [release announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/) they talk about difference between old version and new version.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, I only posted this after days of searching for an answer, then the answer appeared! In Docker-speak, "latest" does not point to 1.1, even though 1.1 is the latest released version. I changed the first line of my dockerfile to read:

FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk-msbuild

and now it's building.

Answer (score 0):

you shou use 1.1.0-sdk-msbuild if your project absence projet.json